# .emacs linked to emacs.link,open emacs.link in emacs-lisp mode

Tags: major-mode, symbolic-links

Say I have a symbolic link `.emacs` link to `emacs.link`,so when I open `emacs.link`,the associated buffer's major mode is *Fundamental mode*.
I want `emacs.link`'s major mode  *Emacs-Lisp*.

Another example is: for a symbolic link `.bashrc` link to `bashrc.link`,I want `bashrc.link` opened in `sh-mode`.

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce what you see, preferably from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this reliably. If you created a link called `.bashrc` to your `.emacs`, how would Emacs know which major mode to use? You could of course do something like `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("emacs\\.link" . emacs-lisp-mode))`

Comment: @Erik,the link has a pattern,`.bashrc` will be link `bashrc.link,`.emacs` link `emacs.link`.
I have fix the problem but forget to self answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging *files.el* in emacs src code,I got the solution.

The procedure:

1. once the `file.link` file opened,figure out `.file` name by `buffer-file-name`.
2. find `.file` major mode by search `auto-mode-alist`
3. call `set-auto-mode-0`

The code:

```
(defun zil/link-file-open-hook ()                                                                                                                                       
 "for link files' major-mode in dot-file"                                                                                                                              
 (let* ((bn (buffer-file-name))                                                                                                                                        
        (dot-name (concat "." (file-name-base bn)))                                                                                                                    
        (mode (assoc-default dot-name auto-mode-alist 'string-match)))                                                                                                 
    (if (and (string= "link" (file-name-extension bn)))                                                                                                                 
         (string-match-p "dot" bn))                                                                                                                                 
    (and mode (set-auto-mode-0 mode t))))                                                                                                                           

 (add-hook 'find-file-hook 'zil/link-file-open-hook)
```